# Closure multiplate call function im javascript

Tags: javascript

Example i write down

```
myFunc('asdas')
```

It's console.log me

```
'asdas'
```

Then after i write down

```
myFunc('as')('ds')('ko')....('other')
```

function must console.log me

> "as ds ko .... other"

I tried do realize this but have many problems with it.

```
function me (str){
    //var temp = str;
    return function mes(val) {
        val += ' '+ str;
        console.log(val);
        //return mes;
    }
}
```

How correctly realize this function?

Comment: How should the inner compiler know, what's the last call (and do the output)? Would be easier, if you had some kind of "end" function: `myFunc('as')('ds')('ko')....('other').write()`.

Comment: It would also be easier to use multiple arguments: `myFunc('as','ds', ...)` or take a single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a bit funny, but works:

```js
concat = function(x, val) {
    val = (val || "") + x;
    var p = function(y) { return concat(y, val) };
    p.toString = function() { return val };
    return p
}

x = concat('a')('b')('c')('d');
document.write(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate multiple console logs and chain it like this:

```
function me(str) {
    console.log(str);
    return me; // or whatever you called the function
}

me(1)(2)(3);
```

As far as I'm aware though, there's no way for the function to know when it should be outputting if you're just chaining, though.

The best option I can think of would be this:

```
function me(str) {
    me.str = me.str || ''; // make sure me.str is set

    // set me.write if this is the first call to me()
    me.write = me.write || function() {
        console.log(me.str);
    }

    me.str += (me.str.length ? ' ' : '') + str; // add a space if needed
    return me; // or whatever you called the function
}

me(1)(2)(3).write();
```

Comment: Ninja downvote for a correct answer? Thanks, John Doe